# Background-image in IE11

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, internet-explorer-11

I have simple `Label` for which I would like to set background-image.

```
label{
content: '';
opacity: 1;
position: absolute;
display: block;
visibility: visible;
right: 2px;
top: 0;
background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-basic/24/Ok-icon.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: whitesmoke;
width: 23px;
height: 23px;
}
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/17b7z4bb/)**

Few suggestion that I've tried were :

- separate background image and color.

From `background: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-basic/24/Ok-icon.png) no-repeat;`

to `background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-basic/24/Ok-icon.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;`

- Set width and height.

But this doesn't help.

---

I am working from Win8.1 IE 11. Maybe there is problem?

Comment: The background id appearing in my IE11

Comment: @Shl, hmmm, than something in my settings...?

Comment: @demo did you ever figure this out?